# VS2012 WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.0 can not include trd lib

Tags: visual-studio-2012, driver

```
#pragma comment(lib, "libmcrypt.lib")
```

When the platform is Visual Studio 2012 (v110), it is OK. But, when platform is WindowsApplicationForDrivers8.0, it reports error LNK2019

When I include OpenSSL in my project, I'm getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

From the MSDN.

The following sample generates LNK2019:

```
// LNK2019.cpp
// LNK2019 expected
extern char B[100];   // B is not in avilable to the linker
int main() {
   B[0] = ' ';
}
```

LNK2019 can also occur when you declare but do not define a static data member. The following sample generates LNK2019:

```
// LNK2019b.cpp
// LNK2019 expected
struct C {
   static int s;
};

// Uncomment the following line to resolve.
// int C::s;

int main() {
   C c;
   C::s = 1;
}
```

Please go to the MSDN link for full explanation

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/799kze2z(v=vs.80).aspx